# Amazon Athena: Split line separated by |

Tags: amazon-athena

I have log files where each line has the format:

```
key1=val1|key2=val2|key3=val3
```

How do I make Amazon Athena split this into columns `key1`, `key2` and `key3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a table based on Regex. This way you can define the parsing scheme for your table.

For you sample, the DDL would look like this.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  key1 string,
  key2 string,
  key3 string
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "input.regex" = "^key1=([^\\|]+)\\|key2=([^\\|]+)\\|key3=([^\\|]+)$"
) LOCATION 's3://njams-data/test/';
```